# Connect Oracle cloud Database using JDBC java

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I have database username and password to access oracle db and also have service url like https://X-X.X.X.oraclecloudapps.com/apex/.

Can anybody know how to connect this db using JDBC connection.

I tried using oracle thin driver but somehow it failes.
Sample java code:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//X.X.X.X.oraclecloudapps.com:1521/sid", "username", "****");
```

It throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

I don't know SID here, it would be helpful if anybody give steps to find SID/ServiceName from Oracle Cloud dashboard.

Comment: What did you do, exactly? What was the error message when it failed to connect? Please edit your question to provide an answer to these questions. Take the site tour and see the "help us to help you" blog, both at the bottom left of the page.

Comment: if this is the schema service, there's only access over REST and via the APEX Dashboard. If you're on our DBaaS, then you have to use SSH to access, so setup port forwarding on your jdbc connection to go through a SSH tunnel.

Comment: @Vérace, question edited please see it again.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, How to check that this is a schema service or service is on DBaaS ?

Comment: To get SID i used query SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') FROM DUAL; but it gives every time different result, which is 4 digit integer.

Comment: My database plan is Database S20 of Database Schema Service, let me know in this plan can i connect using JDBC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only three way to connect Database Schema Service.

- From an Oracle Application Express application running in Database Schema Service
- From a Java application running in an Oracle Java Cloud Service
- Through RESTful Web services

Answer (score 3):

You can't use JDBC to connect to the Database Schema Service. You can connect using the API or tools that utilize the REST API. For data upload to Oracle Database Schema Service, use Oracle SQL Developer, the Oracle Application Express SQL Workshop Data Upload Utility or the Oracle Application Express Data Load utility. Read more here: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/dbcs_schema/CSDBU/GUID-3B14CF7A-637B-4019-AAA7-A6DC5FF3D2AE.htm#CSDBU177

Answer (score -2):

Try the following JDBC URL to resolve the issue

"**jdbc:oracle:thin:@host-address:1521/sid**";

Note **/** is used after port and Not **:**

Comment: A URL that ends with `/sid` isn't valid. It's either `:sid` (which is deprecated) or `/servicename`.